# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, web

I ran ng build in my angular project[The command created a folder called 'public'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuZaI.png)   [Public folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgrCA.png)

When I start my node API on 3000 port I 'call' this file[Routes in app.all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UakQu.png)

[Index.html file of public folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZdMi.png)

But when I start the localhost it returns this.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m5ec.png)

Comment: As a courtesy to those attempting to assist you, always include code snippets in your question - don't use images. Please review [How to ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Place your catchall route (`app.all(...)`) AFTER the other routes. You are returning `index.html` for every request.